# Orchard CMS Advanced Menu - Replace the Superfish-based menu widget with clean one

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, menu, orchardcms

Can anyone tell me how I can use the Szmyd's Advanced Menu module with Orchard CMS without any of the superfish styles etc?

Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module at installation time replaces the default menu with **StyledMenuWidget**. This widget uses Superfish. You are free to change that - **go to Widgets admin, remove the existing menu widget from Navigation Zone and add new MenuWidget there instead**.

Comment: thanks @pszmyd again for your help. Is it intended that your menu module removes existing classes on menu items and replaces them with a title css class? I am adding menu items to the main menu with my own INavigationProvider, but my custom css classes are getting removed

Comment: any chance of a response @pszmyd?

Comment: @Brendan Sorry - missed that one. Your classes are applied to **li** element, that surrounds the link. Link only gets "title" class atm. It means a minor change to your CSS though - ".myclass" to ".myclass a" to style the link.

Comment: @Piotr Szmyd When I use WebMatrix to download orchard 1.6, the advanced menu didn't work. It says:        Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Szmyd' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)         Modules\Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu\Views\Menu.cshtml        Line2: using Szmyd.Orchard.Modules.Menu.Models;